# Pass a class with Generic parameter to another class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics

I have 2 classes in Delphi XE5 and pass one to another :

```
  TfrmBaseList = class(TForm)
  private
    FListOwner: TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity>;
  public
    constructor Create(AListOwner: TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity>); virtual;
  end

  TSystemBaseList<T: TSystemColumnEntity> = class(TPersistent)
  public
    procedure Execute;
    property SelectedValues: TObjectList<T> read 
  end;


  procedure TSystemBaseList<T>.Execute;
  var
    frmList: TfrmBaseList;
  begin
   //frmList := TfrmBaseList.Create(Self<T>)
   //frmList := TfrmBaseList.Create(Self<TSystemColumnEntity>)  
   frmList := TfrmBaseList.Create(???????)
  end;
```

How can I Pass **TSystemBaseList** to Constructor of TfrmBaseList class?

This constructor only create a Form and then assign AListOwner to FListOwner,
Can I change this constructor to property like this:

```
TfrmBaseList = class(TForm)
private
  FListOwner: TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity>;
public
  property ListOwner: TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity> read FListOwner write FListOwner;
end
```

And how do I set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor expects a concrete instantiation, an instance of:

```
TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity>
```

You are supplying an uninstantiated generic instance of type:

```
TSystemBaseList<T>
```

You have to supply a concrete instance to that constructor. In its current form you cannot instantiate the form from `TSystemBaseList<T>.Execute`.

You might think that because `T` must derive from `TSystemColumnEntity` that  `TSystemBaseList<T>` would be compatible with `TSystemBaseList<TSystemColumnEntity>`. But that is not the case because there is no generic variance supported. Read more on this topic here: [Generics and variance](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.fr/2014/10/generics-and-variance.html).

One way forward would be to make the form type generic too. Although that does not play well with the IDE form designer. I suspect a more radical re-design is needed to solve your problem. I won't offer advice on that re-design because I don't know the problem.

Comment: Can I change this constructor to property(I edited my question)?

Comment: No, that's exactly the same problem. You can only pass an uninstantiated generic to a generic method or a method or property or field of a generic class.

Comment: I have a List with Values(TListObject of Generic type) property. List called a Form and it's supposed selected rows (from grid on form) save in List.Values property. For this reason I want to send List as a Owner (ListOwner not component owner) to Form because Form should have access to the List.Values to add items.

Comment: I answered the question you asked I think.